# Problemas al instalar composer en ubuntu linux

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, xampp, composer

Estoy tratando de instalar composer en ubuntu linux, esto para utilizar laravel, pero me sale el siguiente error

```
zsh: command not found: php
```

Lo intento instalar desde composer, con el siguiente comando:

```
php -r "copy('getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

Utilizo xampp como servidor.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás tratando de instalarlo?¿Desde los repositorios de ubuntu o desde el de composer?

Comment: Desde composer, con el siguiente comando, php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

Comment: Parece que tu shell no está encontrando el ejecutable de php. ¿Que te devuelve si tipeas `whereis php` en tu terminal?

Comment: Escribe `php --version` en tu terminal y dime que versión te muestra

Answer (score 0):

Para instalar composer de forma global en ubuntu debes mover `composer.phar` a `/usr/local/bin/composer` como se indica en la documentación.

Pasos a seguir:

- Descargar localmente la última versión ([documentación](https://getcomposer.org/download/))

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'c31c1e292ad7be5f49291169c0ac8f683499edddcfd4e42232982d0fd193004208a58ff6f353fde0012d35fdd72bc394') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Mover para utilizar composer globalmente ([documentación](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos)):

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Algunos requisistos previos son:

- Tener **PHP>5.3.2** instalado
- Extensiones necesarias:

  - json, phar, filter, hash, iconv, openssl, zlib
- Configurar en php.ini `allow_url_fopen = On`

Puedes comprobar la versión php con el comando `php -v` y ver las extensiones instaladas con `php -m`. También puedes crear un archivo php y poner dentro la función `phpinfo();` ([documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.phpinfo.php)) para ver mas detalles.

---

Nota:

Si composer ha sido instalado manualmente y no desde un gestor de paquetes puedes también actualizarlo a la última versión con el comando `composer self-update`, para saltar a la versión major 2.x utilizar `composer self-update --2` ([la versión 2.0.0 fue liberada el 2020-10-24](https://getcomposer.org/download/)).

Answer (score 0):

He logrado instalar laravel con los siguientes comandos.

```
sudo apt-get install curl

sudo apt-get install mcrypt php-json php-cli

sudo su

cd /usr/local/bin

php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

php composer-setup.php

php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

mv composer.phar composer

cd /opt/lampp/htdocs

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel
```